# Open language documentation?

Tags: atom-editor, help-files

In GitHub's [Atom](https://atom.io/) editor, is there a package to find the current word in the file-type-associated language documentation?

E.g.

1. cursor on word or word selected, `..cloneNode(true);`
2. press `F1` (or other common keyboard key/shortcut)
3. Atom [extension] opens [/searches] documentation for cloneNode
4. help file or web site opens https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode